# Newcommand to Work for Each Digit in a Parameter

Tags: macros, parameters

I was hoping someone might know how to modify the following to give the output in the second image without having to repeat the `\myarc{~}` for each digit.

I'm using LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}

%underline
\newcommand{\myarc}[1]{\wideparen{#1}}

\begin{document}

$13\myarc{682}75$

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's very easy with `xparse`: we split the list “at nothing”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myarc}{>{\SplitList{}}m}{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\wideparen}%
}

\begin{document}

$13\myarc{682}75$

\end{document}
```

The process is easy: each digit is fed to `\wideparen`, so that `\myarc{123}` becomes `\wideparen{1}\wideparen{2}\wideparen{3}`.

[image]

If you want to avoid overlapping, add a small space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myarc}{>{\SplitList{}}m}{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\widerparen}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\widerparen}{m}{\mskip.3mu\wideparen{#1}\mskip.3mu}

\begin{document}

$13\myarc{682}75$

\end{document}
```

This is the same as before, but using `\widerparen`, that adds a bit of space on the left and right of the digit.

[image]

If you want to just put the arc over the first and the last digit in the argument, the code is a bit more complex. I've left `\myarc*` to print an arc over each digit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\widerparen}{m}{\mskip.3mu\wideparen{#1}\mskip.3mu}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myarc}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \enas_arc_all:n { #2 } } % the call is \myarc*{123}
   { \enas_arc_fl:n { #2 } }  % the call is \myarc{123}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_enas_arc_input_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \enas_arc_all:n
 {% this is essentially the same as the easy version
  % split the input one digit at a time
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_enas_arc_input_seq { } { #1 }
  % apply \widerparen to each digit
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_enas_arc_input_seq
   {
    \widerparen{##1}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \enas_arc_fl:n
 {% we only want the arc on the first and last digit
  % split the input one digit at a time
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_enas_arc_input_seq { } { #1 }
  % get the first item and store it
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_enas_arc_input_seq \l_enas_arc_digit_tl
  % apply \wideparen to it
  \wideparen { \l_enas_arc_digit_tl }
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l_enas_arc_input_seq
   {% there are other digits, get the last one
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l_enas_arc_input_seq \l_enas_arc_digit_tl
    \seq_if_empty:NTF \l_enas_arc_input_seq
     {% they were only two, add some space
      \mskip .6mu
     }
     {% there are digits in between, print them
      \seq_use:Nn \l_enas_arc_input_seq {}
     }
    % print the last digit
    \wideparen { \l_enas_arc_digit_tl }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$13\myarc{6}8275$

$13\myarc{68}275$

$13\myarc{682}75$

$13\myarc*{682}75$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would explain that recently added code for me in detail. I'm new to using macros, and it would be great if I could understand what I'm doing.

Comment: @EnasM I added some more comments, but explaining all of `expl3` would be too much

Answer (score 10):

Here, I set up an iteration, taking a token at a time from the argument and applying the `\wideparen` to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}

%underline
\newcommand{\myarc}[1]{\myarchelp#1\relax}
\def\myarchelp#1#2\relax{\wideparen{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\myarchelp#2\relax\fi}

\begin{document}

$13\myarc{682}75$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The OP asks in a comment if the action can be limited to the first and last characters of the argument.  Something like this seems to  work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\newcommand{\myarc}[1]{\myarcaux#1\relax}
\def\myarcaux#1#2\relax{\wideparen{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else%
  \myarchelp#2\relax\relax\fi}
\def\myarchelp#1#2#3\relax{\ifx\relax#2\wideparen{#1}\else#1\fi\ifx\relax#2\relax\else%
  \myarchelp#2#3\relax\fi}

\begin{document}

$13\myarc{682}75$

$13\myarc{645682}75$

$13\myarc{62}75$

$13\myarc{6}75$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want to have only the first and last digits under the arc no matter how many digits I have? Ex, `$13\myarc{6827}5$` should give output equivalent to `$13\wideparen{6}82\wideparen{7}5$`, `$13\myarc{682}75$` should give output equivalent to `$13\wideparen{6}8\wideparen{2}75$`, and `$13\myarc{68}275$` should give output equivalent to  `$13\wideparen{6}\wideparen{8}275$`

Comment: @EnasM See my edit.